# Python - formatted chat client

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have made a chat server and client which uses basic socket connections to send messages to a server which then sends them to all connected users. This was all done using `print` in the command line and so the next step was to make a GUI, using Tk (Python 2.7).

The problem I now have is displaying the received messages in the client with wrapping.

At first I tried using a Listbox, which worked perfectly apart from the fact that there is apparently no way to wrap text on a Listbox.

Secondly I tried using a text box which was a total disaster since i couldn't find any methods for printing text in it without typing it out.

Thirdly I tried a canvas, which does support word wrapping and has the ability to create text, however I had some problems with the text being printed in the right place after the wrapping as well as the scroll bar not working

[image].

So can any of those issues be solved, or am I barking up totally the wrong tree and there is a really easy way to do this?

Here's the code i have at the moment for the Canvas:

```
self.chatspace.create_text(5, i, text = recv_data, anchor=NW, width=175)
i = i + (((len(recv_data) / 175) + 1) * 15)
```

I realise that `len()` returns the number of characters in the string and not the length in pixels.

Sorry for asking 3 questions, i am totally stumped, I've been working on this for 4 hours.

Comment: What does tis mean? "i couldn't find any methods for printing text in it without typing it out." Are you literally talking about printing with a printer? What do you mean by "typing it out"?

Comment: oh, sorry that wasn't quite clear, what i meant was in a way similar to 'print "x"' (printing in the command line), i cant think of any better way to explain it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the text widget. To insert text into the widget, use the `insert` method:

```
The_widget.insert("end", "hello, world")
```

This is documented pretty much in all Tkinter documention. For example, see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.insert-method

Comment: I can't believe i was that ignorant to miss that, but thank you so much, it works perfectly now