# Is there a way to get all keyboard input from turtle in python not just specific keys

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, python-turtle

Is there a way to get all keyboard input from turtle in python not just specific keys. I am aware I can use `turtle.onkey(up, "Up")` to call a function on a specific key press but I want to be able to get any key press without having to go through and manually set a function for every single key as I want to be able to display user text input in the turtle window directly without having to use console or alternatives like that.

Comment: Just make a for loop and you register all the keys? Keys are mapped to integers... check on internet the max value for keys and simply pass that to the onkey function

Comment: Maybe [Update turtle/gui while waiting for input python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620960/update-turtle-gui-while-waiting-for-input-python/73589137#73589137) solves the problem for you? The behavior expected here is rather vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is no, you can't do it only with turtle, turtle built with tkinter and tkinter don't have that option, if you want to do it you should import other modules like pyinput, but pyinput may not that easy to learn (I didn't really try)
I just use the module "keyboard" (to download it on windows go to command prompt and type pip install keyboard) but I didn't try all of the functions with that module and I don't know if it is fully trusted, I just use it for one simple function which is

```
from keyboard import is_pressed as pressed
if keyboard.pressed('h'): # just for example it should be a string
    # what ever you want to do here
```

so I really recommended to just learn pyinput cause it is really has more options, but if you don't use a lot of options  you can do like me.